# The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part

Server Error when updating a field:

> The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your
>   Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

```
var creatdbyfield = spList.Fields["Created By"];
creatdbyfield.ReadOnlyField = false;
creatdbyfield.Update();
```

Crashing on the Update() call. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code :

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;  //here web is the spweb object
var creatdbyfield = spList.Fields["Created By"];
creatdbyfield.ReadOnlyField = false;
creatdbyfield.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Reference - [Exception : "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/03/15/exception-the-security-validation-for-this-page-is-invalid-click-back-in-your-web-browser-refresh-the-page-and-try-your-operation-again/)